# How to optimize JOIN in Oracle in case we are interested only on first matching child row?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have parent table lets say P, with Id, Name, and Type.

```
P(
  id (pk),
  name,
  type (type in (1..10) )
)
```

And I have a child table that references P, lets say the table is called B:

```
B (
  id,
  date,
  other columns,
  parent_id
)
```

Now here is the problem: table `P` has not so many records, but table `B` is really huge.
In case if `Type = 3`, the date in `B` will be always the same for the parent record.

So I would like to get all records from `P` with `type = 3`, and corresponding Date from table `B`. What is the best way to do it, taking into consideration that B is very big?

I was thinking to write something like

```
Select b.parent_id, p.name, max(b.date)
from B b
join P p on p.id = b.parent_id
group by b.parent_id, p.name
where p.type = 3
```

Here `max(b.date)` or `min(b.date)` dose not matter because the Date is the same.
But table `B` is very big.
Wouldn't it be better to select only from `P` and do join to `B`, for example "child row that has min id", or basically any child row?

```
Select p.id, p.name, b.date
from P p
join B b on (p.id = b.parent_id and "take only first matching row")
where p.type = 3
```

Comment: Get only 1 row from B using `FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY` in Oracle 12c.

Comment: thanks a lot, we have Oracle 12. Can you please write how this Join will look like? or maybe the whole query?

Comment: how "huge" is B? what are the indexes on B?

Comment: B has ~ 100 mln of rows. P has ~ 6,000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, and assuming you have an index on `b (parent_id)`. If the data you have is:

```
create table p (
  id number(6) primary key not null,
  name varchar2(20),
  type number(2)
);

insert into p (id, name, type) values (10, 'John', 2);
insert into p (id, name, type) values (11, 'Peter', 3);
insert into p (id, name, type) values (12, 'Albert', 3);
insert into p (id, name, type) values (13, 'Mary', 4);
insert into p (id, name, type) values (14, 'Diego', 3);

create table b (
  id number(6),
  date1 date,
  parent_id number(6),
  constraint fk1_b foreign key (parent_id) references p (id)
);

create index ix1_b on b (parent_id);

insert into b (id, date1, parent_id) values (101, timestamp '2018-01-01 12:34:56', 10);
insert into b (id, date1, parent_id) values (102, timestamp '2018-01-02 12:34:57', 11);
insert into b (id, date1, parent_id) values (103, timestamp '2018-01-03 12:34:58', 11);
insert into b (id, date1, parent_id) values (104, timestamp '2018-01-04 12:34:59', 11);
insert into b (id, date1, parent_id) values (105, timestamp '2018-01-04 12:55:10', 12);
insert into b (id, date1, parent_id) values (106, timestamp '2018-01-04 12:55:11', 12);
insert into b (id, date1, parent_id) values (107, timestamp '2018-01-04 12:55:12', 12);
```

The query would be:

```
select p.*, bl.date1
  from p,
  lateral (
    select * from b where b.parent_id = p.id fetch next 1 rows only
  ) bl
  where p.type = 3;
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME    TYPE  DATE1
--  ------  ----  ---------------------
11  Peter   3     2018-01-02 12:34:57.0
12  Albert  3     2018-01-04 12:55:10.0
```

Now, in case there are rows in `p` without any rows in `b` ("Diego" in my example) you would need an outer join:

```
select p.*, bl.date1
  from p
  outer apply (
    select * from b where b.parent_id = p.id fetch next 1 rows only
  ) bl
  where p.type = 3;
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME    TYPE  DATE1
--  ------  ----  ---------------------
11  Peter   3     2018-01-02 12:34:57.0
12  Albert  3     2018-01-04 12:55:10.0
14  Diego   3     <null>
```

Cheers!

Comment: nb `lateral` and `outer apply` are not available for all Oracle versions, they are available in 12c

Comment: I am impressed :) We have 12c version, but I have never seen "lateral" or "outer apply" before. Is "outer apply" the same as Left join? Is it something very new, coming only with Oracle 12c?

Comment: Welcome to the present! ;) `LATERAL` (aka `CROSS APPLY`), and `OUTER APPLY` are [newer] ways of joining **correlated** "table expressions". As far as I know they are available in Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, and SQL Server. Informix may have them but I haven't witnessed them there. Pretty useful for some special cases, like yours.

Answer (score 1):

give this a try:

```
Select p.id, p.name, (select b.date from B where p.id = b.parent_id and rownum = 1) date
from P p
where p.type = 3
```